# How to change column Data type dynamically in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the fixed file that need to split based on the position and the datatype same as
SchemaFile. How to change the Datatype ? I can Cast each column but my requirement to
convert dynamically using pyspark

** TextFile **

```
"00120181120xyz1234"
"00220180203abc56792"
"00320181203pqr25483"
```

** Schema File **

```
{"Column":"id","From":"1","To":"3","dtype":"int"}      
{"Column":"date","From":"4","To":"8","dtype":"date"}    
{"Column":"name","From":"12","To":"3","dtype":"String"}    
{"Column":"salary","From":"15","To":"5","dtype":"int"}
 
datafile=spark.read.csv("text.dat")  
SchemaFile=spark.read.json("text.json")  
sfDict = map(lambda x: x.asDict(), SchemaFile.collect())
```

**finaldf splited based on position **

```
finaldf = inputfiledf.select(*[substring(str='value', 
pos=int(row['from']),len=int(row['to'])).alias(row['column']) for row in sfDict])
finaldf.printSchema()
root |-- id: string (nullable = true)      
|-- date: string (nullable = true)    
|-- name: string (nullable = true)  
|-- salary: string (nullable = true)
```

Expecting Date datatype as Date and Salary datatype as Int.Can we do this dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You almost had the solution. You just need to add `.cast()` inside of your list comprehension:

```py
finaldf = inputfiledf.select(
    *[
        substring(str="value", pos=int(row["from"]), len=int(row["to"]))
        .alias(row["column"])
        .cast(row["dtype"])
        for row in sfDict
    ]
)
```

It *may* also be better to replace `sfDict` with the following:

```py
def schema():
    with open("text.json", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            yield json.loads(line)


sfDict = schema()
```

Comment: Date filed is Null                                                                                                                 

 finaldf.show()
+---+-----+----+------+
| id|date1|name|salary|
+---+-----+----+------+
|001| null| xyz| 12341|
|002| null| abc| 56792|
|003| null| pqr| 25483|
+---+-----+----+------+
 finaldf.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date1: date (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: string (nullable = true)